# How can i write this query in MySql?

Tags: mysql

I have a table:

```
    question_id | user_id | answer | weight
        213     |   22    |   25   |   50
        213     |   106   |   75   |   50
        216     |   22    |   100  |   50
        216     |   106   |   0    |   50
```

I want to write a MySql query that will calculate, for two specified `user_id`'s:

`user1's weight * (user1's answer - user2's answer)`

and sum this values for all `question_id`'s. So, for the example above, if `user1`'s id is 22 and `user2`'s id is 106:

`50*(25-75)+50*(100-0)=2500`

Comment: You're saying, *for **two** specified `user_id`s* but your example only says `user1` id is 22. What's `user2` id in your example?

Comment: @lurker: That can only be 106 ...

Comment: @lurker `user2` is 106. Sorry, i had an error in the example calculation.

Comment: @Glorfindel although I agree the value could be deduced, I think it's important for the OP to be specific. I've seen way too many typos and mis-specified problems on SO to make assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a self join:

```
SELECT SUM(u1.weight * (u1.answer - u2.answer)) AS total
FROM table u1
JOIN table u2 ON u2.question_id = u1.question_id
WHERE u1.user_id = 22 AND u2.user_id = 106
```

Make sure the column types are not "unsigned", otherwise, you'll need to cast the values to signed.

Comment: Great answer, you get the same results I did with half as many lines.

Answer (score 0):

I started by writing a case statement to get each players score and weight per question like this:

```
SELECT
  question_id,
  MAX(CASE WHEN user_id = 22 THEN answer ELSE null END) AS user1Score,
  MAX(CASE WHEN user_id = 22 THEN weight ELSE null END) AS user1Weight,
  MAX(CASE WHEN user_id = 106 THEN answer ELSE null END) AS user2Score,
  MAX(CASE WHEN user_id = 106 THEN weight ELSE null END) AS user2Weight
FROM myTable
GROUP BY question_id;
```

The reason I had to add MAX() was because without it I would get two rows, one for user1 with user2's values as null, and one for the opposite. This helps combine them all into one row per question.

Once I had those results, I used it as a subquery to preform the calculation you want:

```
SELECT SUM(user1Weight * (user1Score - user2Score)) AS total
FROM(
  SELECT
    question_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN user_id = 22 THEN answer ELSE null END) AS user1Score,
    MAX(CASE WHEN user_id = 22 THEN weight ELSE null END) AS user1Weight,
    MAX(CASE WHEN user_id = 106 THEN answer ELSE null END) AS user2Score,
    MAX(CASE WHEN user_id = 106 THEN weight ELSE null END) AS user2Weight
  FROM myTable
  GROUP BY question_id) tmp;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/79d0c/10) example.